# What is the replacement for Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I upgraded from ASP.NET Core 1.1 to 2.0 and am now having 401 Unauthorized responses get changed to 302 Redirect responses. This was previously an issue for me in 1.1 and was mitigated with the following code:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(identityOptions =>
{
    identityOptions.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;
})
```

However, there is no longer a `Cookies` property on `identityOptions`.

I have tried adding the following as well (and also note that I previously did not need this extension method in my app):

```
services.AddCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions => {
    cookieAuthenticationOptions.LoginPath = ""; // also tried null
    cookieAuthenticationOptions.AccessDeniedPath = ""; // also tried null
    cookieAuthenticationOptions.LogoutPath = ""; // also tried null
});
```

That code appears to have no effect to the default redirect paths or behaviors. How can I prevent these redirects in Core 2.0?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As explained in https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/262, you must now configure the default scheme handlers at the global level, using the `services.AddAuthentication()` extension.

To prevent the cookies handlers registered by Identity from handling challenges, replace `DefaultChallengeScheme` by the scheme corresponding to a different handler (e.g the JWT bearer handler).

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```

If - for whatever reason - choosing a different handler is not an option for you, then you'll have to use `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie()` to register a custom `CookieAuthenticationEvents.(On)RedirectToLogin` event to change the way Identity returns a "unauthorized response".

Here's an example returning a 401 response:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

Comment: In Core 1.1, I use the existing cookie handlers implementation to react to the ```[Authrorize]``` attribute in my ```Controller```s (which is where I assume the existing Challenge logic is called to compare cookie values to the user database). However, the only modification I want to make is on failure to simply return a 401 instead of a redirect, and keep all the rest of Identity's existing Cookie challenge logic.

Comment: @MatthewStevenMonkan as I said, `AutomaticChallenge` is no longer a thing and the default challenge scheme must be registered at the global level. If you don't change `DefaultChallengeScheme`, then the default cookies handler will be triggered when using `[Authorize]`. If - for whatever reason - choosing a different handler is not an option for you, then you'll have to use `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie()` to register a custom `CookieAuthenticationEvents.RedirectToLogin` event to change the way Identity returns a "unauthorized response" (e.g to return a 401 response).

Comment: @KévinChalet I use different DefaultChallengeScheme, but OnRedirectToLogin  from ConfigureApplicationCookie doesn't fire, do you know any other options to catch this event in .net core 3.1?